# Formatting a vector with inconsistent date formats in R

Tags: r, date

Im new to R and working on cleaning a data table and the csv has a column called `Contract.Valid.Until`

```r
df$Contract.Valid.Until <- c("2020", "2021", "2019", "30-Jun-19", "2022", "18-Aug-2021")
```

I now want to convert it into a uniform date type, i found functions for the Year and for the Dates on Stack Overflow but not how to combine them, here are the functions i found

```r
df$Contract.Valid.Until <- lubridate::ymd(df$Contract.Valid.Until, truncated = 2L)

df$Contract.Valid.Until <- as.Date(df$Contract.Valid.Until, "%d-%b-%y")
```

I would be very glad if any of you could help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps `parse_date` would work

```
library(parsedate)
parse_date(c("2020", "2021", "2019", "30-Jun-19", "2022", "18-Aug-2021"))
[1] "2020-01-01 UTC" "2021-01-01 UTC" "2019-01-01 UTC" "2019-06-30 UTC" "2022-01-01 UTC" "2021-08-18 UTC"
```

Comment: Your solution works on the vector i gave but when i try it in my actual column (class characters) it doesnt work.  This is the error message i receive: Warning: 17885 parsing failures.
row col   expected actual
  1  -- date like    2021
  2  -- date like    2022

Comment: If the solution works for the data you provided, you failed to provide a proper reproducible example. Please share data with the columns that failed to parse.

Comment: No my example was correct and the solution aswell, i just had multiple libraries and my programm used the wrong parse_date function. I apoligize, this was my first Stack Overflow question and my first R project, thanks for your help guys